# Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.openjdk.jdi.ReferenceType not found when update android studio 3.0.0

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-studio-3.0

I have migrated my project from 2.2.3 to stable android studio 3.0.0 and set jdk 1.8, Now we run the app. 
 i am getting 
below exception :

```
Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.openjdk.jdi.ReferenceType not found

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/43.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/35.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/108.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/117.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/77.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/86.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/80.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/89.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/17.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/39.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/99.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/108.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/56.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/65.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/52.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/71.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/80.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/mediarouter/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/23.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/87.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/96.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/57.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/66.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/83.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/92.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/27.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/100.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/109.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/53.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/62.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/45.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/10.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/32.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/97.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/106.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/55.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/50.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/89.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/98.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/25.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/47.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/11.jar --input /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/85.jar --output /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/94.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/data/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/CCL_1.10/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/domain/build/libs/domain.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/PagingTabStrip/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/mediarouter/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/playbacktests/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/testutils/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/library/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/50.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/51.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/52.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/53.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/54.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/55.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/56.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/57.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/58.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/59.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/60.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/61.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/62.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/63.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/64.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/65.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/66.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/67.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/68.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/69.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/70.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/71.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/72.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/73.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/74.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/75.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/76.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/77.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/78.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/79.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/80.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/81.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/82.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/83.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/84.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/85.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/86.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/87.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/88.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/89.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/90.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/91.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/92.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/93.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/94.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/95.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/96.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/97.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/98.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/99.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/100.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/101.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/102.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/103.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/104.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/105.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/106.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/107.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/108.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/109.jar --classpath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Desktop/android_project/Movies_13_11/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/110.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/a10253x0/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, and don't know what's the reason.
to be able to build your app you have to kill java tasks

windows cmd -> `taskkill /F /IM java.exe`

but could be cool to know what is the reason ;)